# How to deal with a bad data from data analytic perspective

Tags: excel, data-analysis, alteryx

I have couple of columns (showing only two for reference) as shown below,

```
Date        Region          
Feb 2021    North america  
Jan 2021    South america
Kinsley     Norway
```

here, you can see that the date column has a weird value instead of date and i am trying to find out what is the best way to deal with such data. You might suggest me to delete the whole row or only that value but i am not sure if it is the right way as i might lose some important information about that specific row.

Please suggest what is the best idea?.

i am using Alteryx to read this data from an excel file.